# Please help to modify the \draw[ ->] in tikzpicture to have the overset effect \overset{..}{\to}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, diagrams, tikz-arrows, overset

I want to include the \overset{}{\to}  and \overset{}{\rightarrow} over the \to or the arrow in the following tikzpicture.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,inner sep=1pt,row sep=1em,column sep=1em] (M)
{
 & A &  B & C \\
  & E &  F & G \\
}
;
\draw[ ->] (M-1-2.east) -- (M-1-3.west);
\draw[ ->] (M-1-3.east) -- (M-1-4.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

So the the output of tikzpicture will have something similar to this overset or stackrel type in tikzpicture?

```
$A \overset{ab}{\to}  B \overset{bc}{\to}  C$
```

[image]

### QUESTION

How should we modify the \draw[ ->] in tikzpicture then?

Comment: Welcome. // Just put (without backslash) node[above] {$ab$} after —. For finer horizontal positioning use [above,pos=0.3]

Comment: could you write a full command, and an answer, please?

Comment: Unfortunately not now. For the syntax kindly see here https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.9

Comment: just write a full comment: did you mean this?

Comment: \draw[ ->] \node[above,pos=0.3]{$ab$}(M-1-2.east) -- (M-1-3.west);

Comment: Does have no backslash with the node? Does it compile? Did you check ch. 17.9 ? — node[above] (M-1- … Just follow my words, please.

Comment: actually your comment can already help solving the problem easily - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some variations, to better see the effects.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    demo/.style={above,pos=.2,font={\tiny},red},
 ]
    \matrix[
        matrix of math nodes,
        inner sep=1pt,
        row sep=1em,
        column sep=2cm,
    ] (M)
    {
        ?  & A &  B & C \\
        ?  & E &  F & G \\
    }
    ;
    \draw[ ->] (M-1-2.east) -- node[above] {$ab$} (M-1-3.west);
    \draw[ ->] (M-1-3.east) -- node[demo] {$bc$}(M-1-4.west);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Kindly follow [this checklist](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790), before posting code snippets, to minimize our guessworking and reworking. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks voted +1. I have also accepted your answer, I have a new one still if you could comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703641/309496

Comment: As I see there are already perfect answers.

Answer (score 4):

With `tikz-cd` package?

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=scriptsize]
 A\rar["ab"] & B\rar["bc"] & C  \\
 D           & E            & F
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For other possibilities of drawing commutative diagrams see package documentation.

Comment: Thanks voted +1. I like this but I will try tikzcd next time. I have a new one still if you could comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703641/309496. maybe you will have an answer too

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer based on checking:
https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.9 suggested by MS-SPO.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,inner sep=1pt,row sep=1em,column sep=1em] (M)
{
 & A &  B & C \\
  & E &  F & G \\
}
;
\draw[ ->] (M-1-2.east) -- (M-1-3.west) node[midway,above,pos=0.3]{\,\tiny ab};
\draw[ ->] (M-1-3.east) -- (M-1-4.west) node[midway,above,pos=0.3]{\,\tiny bc};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx. Please consider to always post a MWE on this site, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that. This also applies to questions. A screenshot is also useful.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer not differ from accept  one, as far as I observe. What is point in it?