# tikzpicture: make perfectly horizontal arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, align, tikz-arrows

Excuse me --- How do I adjust the arrow alignment in tikzpicture such that these arrows become perfectly horizontal?

In this case, I think the size of w vs W makes the difference to distort the arrow. But we want to keep the alphabets the same way, only to adjust the arrow being horizontal.

Ideally I prefer using tikzpicture not tikzcd.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb,mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,inner sep=1pt,row sep=1em,column sep=1em] (M)
{
 & {A_p^{w}}{\;} &    {\;}{A_p^{\rm W}} \\
  & {B_p^{y}}{\;} &    {\;}{B_p^{\rm Y}} \\
}
;
\draw[ <-] (M-1-2.east) -- (M-1-3.west) node[midway,above,pos=0.4]{\;\tiny $wW$};
\draw[ ->] (M-2-2.east) -- (M-2-3.west) node[midway,above,pos=0.4]{\;\tiny $yY$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: As long as no actual drawing is involved, I'd simply use `\xrightarrow{w^W}` as the middle element and enclose the two lines in `gather`.  All in `amsmath` and `amssymb`.

Comment: If you would consider answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703635   on your previous question, than you wouldn't face with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by using the `mid east` and `mid west` anchors or by ensuring that all the nodes have the same height, for example, by inserting a `\strut` into each node:

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    inner ysep=1pt, 
    inner xsep=2pt, 
    row sep=1em,
    column sep=1em
] (M) {
    A_p^w & A_p^\mathrm{W} \\
    B_p^y & B_p^\mathrm{Y} \\
};
\draw[<-] (M-1-1.mid east) -- (M-1-2.mid west) 
    node[midway, above] {\tiny $wW$};
\draw[->] (M-2-1.mid east) -- (M-2-2.mid west) 
    node[midway, above] {\tiny $yY$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    inner ysep=1pt, 
    inner xsep=2pt, 
    row sep=1em,
    column sep=1em,
    every node/.append style={
        execute at end node={\strut},
    }
] (M) {
    A_p^w & A_p^\mathrm{W} \\
    B_p^y & B_p^\mathrm{Y} \\
};
\draw[<-] (M-1-1.east) -- (M-1-2.west) 
    node[midway, above] {\tiny $wW$};
\draw[->] (M-2-1.east) -- (M-2-2.west) 
    node[midway, above] {\tiny $yY$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively (since you originally tagged your question as such), use the `tikz-cd` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
    row sep=1em,
    column sep=2em
]
    A_p^w & A_p^\mathrm{W} \arrow[l, "wW"'] \\
    B_p^y \arrow[r, "yY"] & B_p^\mathrm{Y} \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note: TikZ-CD does this by using its own `asymmetrical rectangle` shape where the center is not in the real center but a fixed (but variable, see key `center yshift`) distance above the baseline. So very similar to `mid west` and `mid east` but without having to use these anchors explicitly. Of course, after loading the `cd` library, this shape can be used in a `matrix of (math) nodes` as well.

Comment: I meant add `[anchor=base]` to the matrix options, but that appears to be the default.  `\draw (M-1-1.south west) rectangle (M-1-2.north east);`